# Print multiple images on one page

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports, printdocument, printdialog

I want print some image with 3*4  Dimension or 4*6 in c#

sent an Image (jpg, png, etc) to a function then user selected a Dimension and count of picture , show print dialog and print it.

(for example : Ordering at side by side 12 photos 3*4)
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/19/UntitledNOMD.png

---

Excuse me My English is not good.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code and where are you facing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PrintDocument class object to print that images. there are several methods and tutorials are available on internet. you can findout by searching text in google. "C# PrintDocument Image". 
I think following link will help you to understand how to use PrintDocument class object.
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/127241/Print-Images-in-C